# No user input on previewing a file that has no installed handler

Tags: 18.04, dell, configuration, lts, inspiron

I'm using the included filesystem browser, hitting the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> bar will give a preview of a selected file. If the selected file has no handler there is a popup saying "Additional Package Required", the trackpad and keyboard become inactive, the system gets hot and the fans come on full. I have to power off or reboot. I assume this isn't normal. The system is obviously doing something intensively. I haven't checked network access because I don't want my laptop to cook.

Software load configuration problem?
Any ideas?

My hardware specs are:

- Dell Inspiron 15 5000 with 16GB and SSD
- OS - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- User - Unix sysadmin since 1983; Ubuntu user since June 2018

Comment: The laptop completely froze? You weren't even able to check & kill which process(es) were using so much cpu? Would the laptop really have destroyed itself in another minute? That sounds like it's a hardware problem

Comment: It doesn't freeze in that the CPU is obviously very busy, but the cursor won't move and keyboard input is ignored. It does get very hot very quickly. I only happens when a 'spacebar preview' is requested for a (common) filetype that needs a package download to handle it. It's perfectly repeatable.

Comment: Sounds like it's frozen, if the mouse & keyboard are frozen. Any graphics updates still happen, like a system monitor, (auto-updating/following) syslog, or just top/htop would display the offending processes. Sounds like a bug

Comment: Fwiw, I found the default file mgr (Nautilus) in Ubuntu wanting (annoying & buggy), so I started using Dolphin. I used Gnome for at least a decade, and I'm always installing a lot of KDE apps, so recently switched to Kubuntu (which has Dolphin as the default file mgr), and as a 30+ year Unix user, I have to say I find it preferable. That being said, it does sound like a Nautilus issue, possible upgrade to 18.10 "might" fix it. (Hardware bug unlikely.)

Comment: Since it's repeatable, and if the screen doesn't freeze (?), but only the user input does -- perhaps try running 'top' in a terminal, trigger the issue, and see what's causing the system to thrash? Might be something (some service) that the file manager is calling.

Comment: By running a 'top' in a window next to the Nautilus one while pressing the spacebar for a preview I can see that it's only the keyboard and trackpad function that freeze.

Comment: After a brief pause 'top' shows the top processes are nautilus, sushi-start, and gnome-shell. A ping from another host continues. A 'top' running in an ssh from another host also continues, but there are a higher number of gnome-shell and other gnome processes in the top 8 than by the onboard copy. The ssh version only shows Nautilus and sushi-start occasionally.

Comment: This time it left a Notification which I go after the reboot, which it hasn't done before. It said it was unable to find 'unoconv', with a 'find out more' link to an Ubuntu community repository, where exists. A search from 'Activities', however, does not find it. I'll try a manual install of it.

Comment: After a manual install of 'unoconv' it now works and doesn't freeze the inputs. So now it becomes two problems that are less problematic.
1. - why didn't/can't the automatic download work?
and
2. - why did that failure freeze access to the system?